# Frequency counting program - Timers in 8051

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, assembly, 8051

```
1.MOV TMOD,#15H
2.SETB P3.4
3.MOV R1,#28
4.MOV TL0,#00H
5.MOV TH0,#00H
6.MOV TL1,#00H
7.MOV TH1,#00H
8.SETB TR0
9.HERE2: SETB TR1
10.HERE: JNB TF1, HERE
11.CLR TF1
12.CLR TR1
13.DJNZ R1, HERE2
14.CLR TR0
15.CLR TR1
```

This program written above is to count the frequency of pulse which is present at the pin p3.4. we are using timer 0 as counter, and timer 1 as normal timer.in line 10, the control wastes around 35.75 ms, so in order to make timer 0 active for around 1 second, we are using line 10 for 28 times.

[image]

But here in the image in line 14 they referenced the DJNZ to line 8, why? What is the the point of refilling the register with 00 again? They could have simply clear the TF1 to start the timer again from 00 instead they are stopping the timer in line 13, and again restarting it after filling with 00.

What is the need of stopping the timer and refill it again with 00? Won't just clearing the TF1 (While keeping TR1 is set) make the timer again start counting from 00? Since the roll over value is already 00 and loaded in the timer after overflow. So isn't it that the first program will work better in terms of accuracy?

Comment: The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here which try to discuss the question, might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, then please do that. Any improvements / updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question, as usual. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127953/discussion-on-question-by-sayan-frequency-counting-program).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what's the intention of the user with timer.

If the user's intention was to implement a 16-bit timer that simply runs from `0x0` to `0xFFFF`, overflow, and then cycle through again (say, to do some periodic task):

YEA, he didn't have to stop the timer after the overflow and then reload with `0x0`. Since `TR1` is still set, timer anyway after the overflow, starts from `0x0` and increments again. In this case, clearing `TF1` would be enough.

**Note that**: clearing `TF1` is not resetting/reloading the timer.